# In an Excel cell, why does ="P10-12" < "P1-9" give me TRUE?

Tags: sorting, excel-formula, character-encoding, ascii

Examine the 3rd character position... `"0" vs "-"` (After the identical two lead characters of "P1")

Basically (in ACSII) zero "0" is `0x30` but the the hyphen is ASCII value `0x2D`... But `0x30 > 0x2D` ... so the `TRUE` result should be `"P10-12" > "P1-9"`...

Can someone point me to a description of what is happening?... or (*better still*) a python "`cmp`" function to mimic this?

A similar post [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-sort-text-formatted-cells-in-place-using/465baf9f-3b88-49ea-a0d8-544cfa9714e0).

Comment: LibraOffice Calc and OppenOffice Calc both give: =“P10-12” < “P1-9” as FALSE?  (They have the locals of EN-US) ... my Excel has a default local of EN-AU... maybe locale is an issue?

Comment: This might be the answer "[Sort alphanumeric data where there are hyphens (and Apostrophes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23806543/sort-alphanumeric-data-where-there-are-hyphens) are ignored."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Sort alphanumeric data where there are hyphens (and Apostrophes) are ignored." (Unless the resulting strings are equal, then "-" is sorted last) cf. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23806543/sort-alphanumeric-data-where-there-are-hyphens)